# How do I cast from System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase to System.Web.HttpPostedFile?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

While trying to implement an MVC file upload [example](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx) on Scott Hanselman's blog. I ran into trouble with this example code:

```
foreach (string file in Request.Files)
{
   HttpPostedFile hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFile;
   if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)
      continue;
   string savedFileName = Path.Combine(
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, 
      Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
   hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName);
}
```

I converted it to VB.NET:

```
For Each file As String In Request.Files
    Dim hpf As HttpPostedFile = TryCast(Request.Files(file), HttpPostedFile)
    If hpf.ContentLength = 0 Then
        Continue For
    End If
    Dim savedFileName As String = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName))
    hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName)
Next
```

But I am getting an invalid cast exception from the compiler:

```
Value of type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile'.
```

Hanselman posted his example on 2008-06-27, and I assume it worked at the time.  MSDN doesn't have any similar examples, so what gives?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just work with it as an HttpPostedFileBase.  The framework uses the HttpPostedFileWrapper to convert an HttpPostedFile to an object of HttpPostedFileBase.  HttpPostedFile is one of those sealed classes that are hard to unit test with.  I suspect that sometime after the example was written they applied the wrapper code to improve the ability to test (using HttpPostedFileBase) controllers in the MVC framework.   Similar things have been done with the HttpContext, HttpRequest, and HttpReponse properties on the controller.

Comment: ADDITIONAL INFO: If you're like me and you're creating this function in a separate project you must include the System.Web.Abstractions.dll file in order to reference the HttpPostedFileBase per: http://efreedom.com/Question/1-1911151/CSharp-Reference-HttpPostedFileBase

Comment: @tvanfosson am looking for this information, why HttpPostedFileBase instead of HttpPostedFile? Do you have a link you can share?

Comment: @codingbiz it's because you can mock out the HttpPostedFileBase class for unit testing.  Mocking frameworks generally choke on mocking sealed classes because they use inheritance to create the mock.

Comment: are there other classes that inherit from HttpPostedFileBase? According to that name, it should be an abstract class inherited by other classes? I tried casting it into HttpPostedFile and it didn't go through. I think the name is misleading: makes you assume HttpPostedFile derived from HttpPostedFileBase

Comment: @codingbiz i believe only HttpPostedFileWrapper descends from it. The "base" class and wrapper came after HttpPostedFile and were designed to "correct" the testability issues with it in MVC (and later).

Answer (score 4):

The correct type to use is HttpPostedFileBase.

```
HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[file];
```

Comment: I believe you, but do you have a reference? I'd like to read a little more about the difference between HttpPostedFileBase and HttpPostedFile.