# How to pass a file to a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this controller :

```
   public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            try
            {
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files"),
                                           Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                file.SaveAs(path);
                ViewBag.Message = "Success";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Error:" + ex.Message.ToString();
            }

        return RedirectToAction("NewController", new { myFile : file });
    }
```

My new controller :

```
public ActionResult NewController(HttpPostedFile myFile)
{

}
```

I want to pass "file" to the `NewController` but it gives me an error at `RedirectToAction`. How can I pass correct values to `RedirectToAction` so that it will work? Thanks.

Comment: what is the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The File is potentially very complex object and you can't pass potentially complex object in simple `RedirectToAction`. So you have to store `File` in `Session` to get it in your next redirection but storing data in `Session` is not good due to performance perspective and you have to set `Session` null after retrieving of data from it.
But you can use `TempData` instead which remains alive during subsequent requests and it immediately destroyed after you retrieved data from it.

So just add your file in [TempData](http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-3-applications/) and retrieve it in New Controller Action.

Another thing that i noticed that you are storing `Message` in `ViewBag`. But `ViewBag` becomes null during redirection, so you won't be able to get `ViewBag.Message` in your `NewControllerAction` action. To make it accessible in your `NewControllerAction`, you have to store it in `TempData`  but `Message` is going to have simple `string` so you can pass it as parameter to `NewControllerAction` action.

```
 public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
 {
    string Message = string.Empty;
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    try
       {
           string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files"), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
           file.SaveAs(path);
           Message = "Success";
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
            Message = "Error:" + ex.Message.ToString();
       }

       //Adding File in TempData.
       TempData["FileData"] = file;
       return RedirectToAction("NewControllerAction", "NewController", new { strMessage = Message });
 }
```

In your new controller:

```
public ActionResult NewControllerAction(string strMessage)
{
   if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strMessage) && strMessage.Equals("Success"))
    {
       HttpPostedFileBase myFile = TempData["FileData"] as HttpPostedFileBase;
    }
    else
    {
       //Something went wrong.
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems that not as easy as expected - are you sure it not triggering `InvalidCastException` like this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849200/how-do-i-cast-from-system-web-httppostedfilebase-to-system-web-httppostedfile?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I used `as` keyword. It casts objects without throwing any exceptions.